# Phonegap - load external URL in webview not working in release mode apk

Tags: android, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to load external URL in PhoneGap webview using the below mentioned code in my index.html **deviceIsReady()**:

```
window.open('https://google.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');
```

and in config.xml:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-navigation href="https://google.com/*" />
```

The above URL works fine when the code is run using PhoneGap desktop app and viewed in Android mobile using Phonegap Adnroid app.

But when the same code is build in release mode using an .apk generated from PhoneGap cloud and run on Android device by enabling `Unknown source` option in device settings, a blank page is displayed without any error message.

Think I am missing some permission? Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was trying to load a external URL in webview I had to include below plugin which I forgot to include earlier:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser">`